# Write URL on NFC tag in correct format in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nfc

I'm building an NFC writing and reading app. I use this code to write URLs on tags:

```
private func writeTag(_ tag: NFCNDEFTag, for session: NFCReaderSession?) {
    guard let payload = "\u{02}en\(self.url ?? "")".data(using: .utf8) else {
        session!.invalidate()
        return
    }
    let record = NFCNDEFPayload(format: .nfcWellKnown, type: Data(), identifier: Data(), payload: payload)
    let myMessage = NFCNDEFMessage.init(records: [record])
    tag.writeNDEF(myMessage) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            session?.invalidate(errorMessage: "Couldn't write tag")
        } else {
            session?.alertMessage = "Tag is written successfully"
            session!.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

The writing works fine. However, the problem is in payload (URL) format. For example, when I write "https://github.com" as a URL using the code above, and then read what I've just written using another NFC app, I get "enhttps://github.co". So I'm sure the problem is in this line:

```
let payload = "\u{02}en\(self.url ?? "")".data(using: .utf8)
```

I've tried changing it to:

```
let payload = (self.url ?? "").data(using: .utf8)
```

However, again, when I read the tag I've just written from another app, I get "https://github.co" instead of "https://github.com".

How should I convert my URL to data to make it work properly?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: `NFCNDEFPayload.wellKnownTypeURIPayload`

Comment: Did you actually get an answer for this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source can be found at: [How To Make Your Swift App Work With NFC Tags in iOS 13](https://betterprogramming.pub/working-with-nfc-tags-in-ios-13-d08c7d183981)

**According to Apple's NFCReaderSession documentation:**

> You do not create instances of this class. Instead, you create and use an instance of NFCNDEFReaderSession or NFCTagReaderSession. Only one reader session of any type can be active in the system at a time. The system puts additional sessions in a queue and processes them in FIFO order.

So, I'm really not sure how you did create an instance of `NFCReaderSession` and invoked `writeTag`. But it seems that, indeed, the way you are creating `payload` is what's wrong with your code.

To properly define a payload that contains an URL:

```
let uriPayloadFromURL = NFCNDEFPayload.wellKnownTypeURIPayload(
           url: URL(string: "www.github.com")!
        )!
```

By creating an instance of `NFCNDEFReaderSession`, and implementing  `readerSession` as follows,  you get exactly what you are trying to achieve.

```
func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCNDEFTag]) {
    
    let uriPayloadFromURL = NFCNDEFPayload.wellKnownTypeURIPayload(
        url: URL(string: "www.github.com")!
    )!
    
    guard tags.count == 1 else {
        session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Can not write to more than one tag.")
        return
    }
    let currentTag = tags.first!
    
    session.connect(to: currentTag) { error in
        
        guard error == nil else {
            session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Could not connect to tag.")
            return
        }
        
        currentTag.queryNDEFStatus { status, capacity, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Could not query status of tag.")
                return
            }
            
            switch status {
            case .notSupported: session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Tag is not supported.")
            case .readOnly:     session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Tag is only readable.")
            case .readWrite:
                let messge = NFCNDEFMessage.init(records: [uriPayloadFromURL])
                currentTag.writeNDEF(messge) { error in
                    if error != nil {
                        session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Failed to write message.")
                    } else {
                        session.alertMessage = "Successfully configured tag."
                        session.invalidate()
                    }
                }
                
            @unknown default:   session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Unknown status of tag.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah I am using that without success. The raw data field shows properly but not the actual text.

Answer (score 0):

OK this one works for text:

```
let initTextPayload = NFCNDEFPayload.init(
        format: .nfcWellKnown,
        type: "T".data(using: .utf8)!,
        identifier: Data(),
        payload: infoToWriteText.text!.data(using: .utf8)!,
        chunkSize: 0)
```

This link helped me:
https://gist.github.com/DavidPiper94/38b18b189ce40acd26f222a14f54682d